# No adapters were found

Tags: docker, adapter

I looked trough similar problems and get suggestions to follow this document.
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/

I feel like that there is issue with my adapter? But I am not sure how to fix this.

```html
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users> docker run --rm -it --gpus=all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark
Unable to find image 'nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody' locally
nbody: Pulling from nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample
22c5ef60a68e: Pull complete
1939e4248814: Pull complete
548afb82c856: Pull complete
a424d45fd86f: Pull complete
207b64ab7ce6: Pull complete
f65423f1b49b: Pull complete
2b60900a3ea5: Pull complete
e9bff09d04df: Pull complete
edc14edf1b04: Pull complete
1f37f461c076: Pull complete
9026fb14bf88: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:59261e419d6d48a772aad5bb213f9f1588fcdb042b115ceb7166c89a51f03363
Status: Downloaded newer image for nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: WSL environment detected but no adapters were found: unknown.
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker daemon isn't available as a service in any other distro. The way you start and stop Docker is through Docker Desktop.

About your NVIDIA issue; i found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1692) about it, a few google searches with the last two lines of the last code snippet should yield some results.

Comment: Yes, because that integration just exposes the **daemon**, but not a **service**. That means that you can run `docker` commands in those distros, not to mess around with the docker *service*. If you do want that level of control, uninstall Docker Desktop and install the Engine in WSL directly. That way you'll have more fine-grained control over the service it runs & more. Docker Desktop kinda was built to replace just that to have something that is way easier to get started with docker and manage it.

Comment: No, you can do that just fine. You have to distinguish between **using** the docker engine and **managing it's process**.
The `service` command you ran is to start the docker engine itself, which is handled by Docker Desktop and thus obsolete.
However, that doesn't change anything about **running a project**. You can still connect to the daemon completely normally, the only thing that is different is how you start and stop the daemon.